# Problem with fading html pages using JQuery and Ajax

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, fading

As a beginner in coding starting to learn in college, I am trying to complete my first assignment which consist in coding a website on glitch using CSS, HTML and JS (and we have to load data using `$.getJSON()` ).

The problem i encountered from the get go was that I was trying to create a smooth fade transition between the first html page that loads, on which there is one button that is supposed to lead to the second, and the second html page. I tried following this tutorial:

https://www.superhi.com/video/simple-page-transitions-with-jquery-and-javascript (replacing "section" with "body") but for the second page to load I need to refresh the page, it cannot do it on its own (even if the fade in / fade out effect seems to work) and despite the fact that the url do change... can anyone tell me where I mess up ?

Here is the body of my first html page

```
<body>
<div class="content">
<h1><a href="index2.html" id="index2go">Welcome to Greendale</a></h1>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

and here is the JS page

```
$("#index2go").on("click", function(event){
event.preventDefault()
const href = $(this).attr("href")
window.history.pushState(null, null, href)
$.ajax({
url: href,
success : function(data){ 
$("body").fadeOut(300, function(){ 
const newPage = $(data).filter("body").html()
$("body").html(newPage)
$("body").fadeIn(250)
})
}
})
})
```

Thank you very much !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please do not post images of code or errors, because it makes it more difficult for us to help you with your issue.  It is always better to copy and paste the relevant code and/or errors into your question directly.  Please read [Why not to upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: in addition to the above comment, you could use https://jsfiddle.net/ to load your example code into so it could be tested easily.

Comment: On glitch i created 2 html files in the same project which i do not manage to do on jsfiddle...

Comment: @NonoBNY part of the issue I see is that you are adding new `<html>` markup from the called page into the `<body>` tag. That might cause some issues. You may also want to checkout `.load()`. Also when you fade out and then fade in, it may be executing faster than expected, before all items load.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the scope of your project, so this might be beyond it. With FadeIn and FadeOut, you can execute the function at the end of it's transition. With AJAX, it's not exactly the same. It's a little complex yet it means that even while AJAX is processing the Request, further code may execute before data has been returned. So it's best to wrap all the code.

Here is a suggested example:

```js
$(function() {
  function getContent(u, target, fn) {
    var newPage;
    console.log("GET " + u);
    var req = $.ajax({
      url: u,
      cache: false,
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("SUCCESS ", data);
        newPage = $(data).find("body").childern();
        target.html(newPage);
        fn();
      },
      error: function(xhr, stat, error) {
        console.log("ERROR ", xhr, stat, error);
        newPage = $("<div>", {
          class: "error"
        }).html("Error " + stat + ": " + error);
        target.html(newPage);
        fn();
      }
    });
  }
  $("a").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    window.history.pushState(null, null, href);
    $("body").fadeOut(300, function() {
      $("body").html("");
      getContent(href, $("body"), function() {
        $("body").fadeIn(250);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="content">
  <h1><a href="index2.html" id="index2go">Welcome to Greendale</a></h1>
</div>
```